How to setup Visual Studios 2022 to display vbscript code blocks the same as Visual Studios 2019
I am trying to replicate my editor view in VS 2022 to be how it looks in VS 2019.
Here is how it looks in VS 2022

versus the coloring found in VS 2019

I have spent quite a bit of time within the Tools > Options > Environment and Text Editor but have yet to find anything that returns the coloring vs the black text for everything.

Never found the later Visual Studio IDEs any good for editing Classic ASP and VBScript. Would recommend switching to Visual Studio Code which has an array of extensions you can install for ASP Language support and VBScript syntax highlighting.

Relevant question - A good IDE for classic ASP?

My £0.02 worth on this is that you don't need an IDE, just a good text editor.  I've been using EditPlus for years for Classic ASP - it isn't free but it isn't expensive.  That said, Visual Studio gives you intellisense for COM objects you may or may not feel you need.  Where I personally find it useful is in in using Javascript as my server side language. Unlike VBS  JS is case sensitive, and that case sensitivity extends to COM object attributes (eg it doesn't recognise objhttp.setrequestheader, you have to use objhttp.setRequestHeader)

If you select Options from the Tools menu you can set your own colours. Scroll down in the list to the VBS options


Huh - wow, you're right...
